# Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''

Tags: android, unit-testing, testing, android-studio

I am learning to use android robotium and I am trying to make a simple test where it reads the first line of a file and it equals "car" but I am getting

Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''.

*The activity starts a fragment.

```
public class TestReadFromFile extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<PagesActivity> {

private Solo solo;
PagesActivity mPagesActivity;

private Context mContext;


public TestReadFromFile() {
    super(PagesActivity.class);
}

public void testReadLine() throws Exception {

    assertEquals(ReadFromFile.readLine(0, mContext),
            "car");
}

@Override
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    super.setUp();
    mPagesActivity = getActivity();
    mContext = getInstrumentation().getTargetContext();
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}


@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}
}
```

Comment: Can you provide any logs?

Comment: For some reason it wont show logs all it says is                                         Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException''. Check device logcat for details
Test running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'java.lang.NullPointerException'

Comment: Check if your mContext != null before calling assertEquals().

Answer (score 0):

The easy solution would be if your `tearDown()` method is not being called because your code happens to have a `System.exit(0)` somewhere.

```
@Override
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    solo.finishOpenedActivities();
}
```

**Alternatively, I assume that your cached context is null.**
You don't need to save your context in the `setUp()` method. You can access your activity/context easily during test cases with `solo.getActivity()`